# CSS: The content of a grid row is overflowing the page

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

**The Situation**

On my website I have a page for people to listen to my music. The page has a grid element with 3 rows: `#music-header`, `#playlist`, and `#player`. The music-header (header) and player (footer) are 60px tall and the content height is determined dynamically with a `1fr` value.

**The Problem**

When the playlist is loaded with songs, it overflows the page. I have `overflow-y: scroll` set on `#playlist`, but that has yielded no results.

**The Code**

I tried for a good 10 minutes to get the HTML snippet to process my website's code to no avail, so instead I'll provide a link to the broken page:

http://hbms.me/#/music

You'll note the list of songs overflows the page. That list is meant to be contained within the `#content` box.

***NOTE: I am currently using Firefox to view the page.***

Comment: I think `#wrapper` height should be `auto`

Comment: @codesayan nope, that just makes the webpage bigger. I want the content of #playlist to fit within the current height of #wrapper.

Comment: Please edit this question to remove the link of the website, and add blocks of code to show what the HTML was like before the site was fixed. We require this for every question on Stack Overflow for exactly the reason you found out - once and external site is fixed, it is no longer a representation of the problem at hand.

Comment: If you are/were struggling with the code formatting tool, then search for "how to format code on Stack Overflow", and you'll find a stack of resources to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overflow property only will work when you set max-height. So you need to set height for playlist container either using media query or Js. Else, you have to restructure your code to bring the expected view.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that all the vertical height on my webpage is defined in stylesheets as `px` values, so I just set the element height to `calc(100vh - 190px)` with `190px` being the combined vertical height of all other elements on the page. This won't work all the time but it will work here.

Comment: Great. calc property won’t work in all ie browsers. Please make sure all your target browser view is in sync.

Comment: yeah, i just need this to work in chrome, firefox, and most mobile browsers. which it does. works on my old iphone 5s and my android (samsung galaxy s8) as well.

Answer (score 1):

In style.css line 31 check and apply this css, this will fix your problem.

```
#playlist {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 544px;
}
```

Comment: No that did not fix the problem. It displays correctly if I put the website in full screen, but overflows if i shrink it vertically. It needs to fit on any screen height.

Comment: Hello @HarrisonSmith you did not mention that before that you are looking for responsive css. you have to write media query for that.

Comment: I'd have to define a query for every possible screen height, as each screen height value needs the #playlist height to be different.

Comment: Wait let me try fixing without media query.

Comment: Wish you luck... spent at least 3 hours on this myself, and checked stackoverflow for answers to no avail

Comment: Need to structure your code then and only it is possible, I can't work on junk code. I am Sorry.

Comment: For now I will have to use a javascript solution, until I find/think of a better one.

Answer (score 0):

A non-ideal solution would be to use javascript:

```
setInterval(() => {
  // get height of #content
  // subtract by 120 (the header and footer are both 60px)
  // set #playlist height to resulting value
});
```

But alas, that is extremely inefficient.